# vue-native app alternative to flatList or html table equivalent

Tags: html-table, vue-native

I am trying to build a basic vue native app with table. In the official documnetation [page](https://vue-native.io/docs/basic-components.html) all I see is flatList and which does not behave or look lie table at all. SO I tried html table syntax, it gave error.

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You
>   likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
>   or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Any advice or easy alternative?

Check the render method of `ReactVueComponent`.